# Stack Overflow custom filter to watch more than one tags

Tags: discussion

I have been trying out the features of Stack Overflow and found out about the custom filter.

I created a filter to watch multiple tags (HTML, and CSS). But the filter is currently returning all the questions contains both the tags (HTML **AND** CSS). Instead I am wondering if there is a way to do an **OR** operation (say all the questions containing *either* HTML, or CSS, or *both*).